# How to deal with extremely rude Facebook troll?

Tags: problem-users, site-administration, facebook

I had a friend - well, call him one. Our relationship went worse and eventually, I had to block him.

He's still active on one of the social media pages of my community, though, and exploits it. He's trolling - not in the flooding manner, but rather "for the lulz". He does that very rarely (maybe once a month), so it's not necessarily irritating, but here's something I don't know how to deal with.

The way he's trolling is extremely offensive, mocking my ideology and recently he has even made similarly rude statement about my girlfriend.

My question is: should I take it seriously? I mean, I'm aware that trolls tend to be extremely offensive very often (questioning basic values to piss off people), but my common sense says that when someone goes beyond a certain border, then I should take heavier measures - such as writing a post about what not to say, where are these borders, and such.

Should I do so, or just ignore him like every ordinary trolls?

Comment: Do you know this person only on Facebook or do you encounter them away from the computer screen as well?

Comment: @Andy only on Facebook.

Comment: The issue is this is personal, not general.

Comment: @GregChase not exactly, because my community is also involved - he even got a "like" from one of my "fans".

Comment: @DVK I did the latter. I don't prefer agonizing on such problems much, actually, but I needed your opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, also stick to ignoring him. The hard part may be getting other people to ignore him as well. If they do, send them a *private* message with a link to a good article that says [Don't feed the trolls](http://janetfouts.com/never-feed-the-trolls/).

Generally, Facebook even leaves 'friend' posts out of your feed if you do not interact with them. I'm not sure if that applies to Community Pages as well. Regardless, his posts will always fade away to the bottom.

You may feel tempted to delete his posts (in the top-right dropdown next to each post you have either the option *Delete post and remove user* or  *Delete post*), but he will probably also react to that.

The core message is that you **completely** ignore him. Not a hint that he is triggering a reaction.

You can find many other tips googling [Dealing with trolls](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dealing+with+trolls) gives you enough suggestions (Some of them disagree).

Comment: +1: Don't feed the trolls. Not even a little. It's a powerful temptation to avoid, but feeding them just makes them worse.